# Uncaught syntax error in angularjs

Tags: html, css, node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below code to populate data from Parse api into table using Angularjs and bootstrap.But the Javascript in which i defined the controller is not executing. The html code is given below.

**index.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="parseApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body >

<div class= "container" data-ng-controller="ParseController" >
<table class="table" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
<tr data-ng-repeat="temp in user">
            <td>{{temp.email}}</td>
            <td>{{temp.phone}}</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>           
</table>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
var parse = angular.model('parseApp',[]);

function ParseController($scope, $http)
{
$http({method : 'GET',url :'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User',

headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'XXXXXXX',
         'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'XXXXXX',
          }}).success(function(data,status) {

            console.log(data);
$scope.user = data;
}).error(function(data,status)
{

}
parse.controller('ParseController',ParseController);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error

```
.error(function(data,status)
{

});
```

Also, it is angular.module, not angular.model

Comment: Thanks , spelling mistake but still data is not populating in table.

Comment: Now , i am not getting any error, success block is also executing but the data is not populating

Comment: In $scope.user=data ...data is not in json format it is showing [object Object]

Comment: Thanks , actually that spelling mistake was the main problem. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax error is in the error handler:

```
.error(function(data,status)
{

});
```

Comment: Nope , i removed it , even it is not working. I think the error is in the line var parse = angular.model('parseApp',[]); But i am not sure why it is showing the error.